# Error Genexus 17 Query Object

Tags: c#, sql, objeto, genexus

Tengo un Objeto **Query** el cual deseo filtrar por un rango de fechas.

Hay una atributo tipo *fecha* y en los parámetros del objeto defino las variables `&FchDes` tipo *Date* y `&FchHas`.

En los filtros coloco el Filtro `CCVFchVta >= &FchDes y CCVFchVta <= &FchHas`. Al compilar genera el siguiente error:

> error spc0009: Type mismatch in condition: CCVFchVta >= &@FchDes@.
> (Procedure 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest' Source,
> Line: 2, Details) warning spc0047: Variable @FchDes@ not defined;
> N(10.2) assumed. (Procedure
> 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest', Details) warning
> spc0047: Variable @FchHas@ not defined; N(10.2) assumed. (Procedure
> 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest', Details) Failed: SQL
> statement generation error: Type mismatch in condition: CCVFchVta >=
> &@FchDes@. (Query 'TabCom1', Structure)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la definición del Query

Comment: Parece ser que las variables te quedaron definidas como numéricas o no están definidas. En el nodo Parameters del objeto Query, si te posicionas en FchDes y FchHas, debes asegurarte que en la propiedad Data Type tengan el valor Date. Si esto es así, ¿podrías mostrar cómo estás poniendo los Filters?

Comment: Qué raro, tengo uno igual y no me da el error. ¿Qué tienes en la propiedad Output type del Query? ¿Podrías probar basando las dos variables FechaDesde y FechaHasta en el atributo CCCFchVta?